# How i can list aws Security Groups older than 30 days in python?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

```
import boto3 
from datetime import datetime
ec2res = boto3.resource('ec2')
ec2cli = boto3.client('ec2')
now = datetime.now()

def calculator(launch_date, object):
    age = now - launch_date
    intage = int(age.days)
    if intage <= 30:
        print(object)

list_security_groups = ec2cli.describe_security_groups() 
for security_group in list_security_groups['SecurityGroups']:
launch_date = datetime.strptime(security_group['CreationDate'].strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
intage = calculator(launch_date,security_group)
```

or

```
list_security_groups = ec2res.security_groups.all()
for security_group in list_security_groups:
launch_date = datetime.strptime(security_group.launchtime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
intage = calculator(launch_date,security_group)
```

these formats are working for other aws object, but i got KeyError for security groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no concept of a "Creation Date", nor *any* date, for Security Groups.

You could theoretically go through the security group's history in AWS Config to get this information.

Always look at the documentation to see which fields are available.